# What happens to data after SSL Session is over?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am familiar with the "SSL handshake" and how it works between client and server, I am just trying to comprehend what happens after its all over. Say you go through the process of buying something through an HTTPS website. After it is all said and done that information has to be decrypted right? Where does your data go? Is your data decrypted and stored in a database of the company where you purchased your product?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. It would be a better fit for security.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

SSL only encrypts the data as it is `in transit` from the client to the server, or vice-versa.  If you use your web browser to connect to a web server through SSL, and send your credit card information to the web server through SSL, your credit card information is encrypted as it is sent through the internet from your web browser to the web server.  But, once it arrives at the web server, it is decrypted, then there is no telling what could happen to it.  Hopefully the company that operates the server handles your credit card information securely.  But, we've all seen all of the recent cases of sites that have been hacked and millions of credit card numbers have been stolen.

Comment: OK. I figured that was how it worked I just wanted to make sure I understood correctly. Thank you for that